Problem in calling Python executable file with large arguments
From C#, I want to execute python exe file with the arguments. If my arguments are simple and small string, it is fine. But if I send large string, then it throws "The filename or extension is too long"
Below is my code. Please tell how to send large arguments
> ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
> start.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Components\test.exe";
> start.Arguments = string.Format(@" {0} {1} {2}", CAP, SDT, EFF);
> start.UseShellExecute = false;
> start.CreateNoWindow = true;
> Process.Start(start);


In my oppinion, this isn't a problem of python, but of your OS. What is your current Windows ? Is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled  set to 1 ? It could be for sure something else too ...

how big this path AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory when error is thrown?
